# How to dinamically push elements into a Javascript object in JSON format

Tags: javascript, json

We are trying to dinamically create a json object with a for cycle. The result should be something like this:

```
posJSON = [ 
    {
        "position": [msg[0].Longitude, msg[0].Latitude],
        "radius": 0.05,
        "color": [255, 255, 0, 255]
    },
    {
        "position": [msg[1].Longitude, msg[1].Latitude],
        "radius": 0.05,
        "color": [255, 0, 0, 255]
    }
]
```

If we just create the object using this code ^ everything works fine, but if we try to dinamically create the object like this:

```
for(i=0; i < Object.keys(msg).length; i++) {
    posJSON.push({
        "position": [msg[i].Longitude, msg[i].Latitude],
        "radius": 0.05,
        "color": [255, 255, 0, 255]
    });
}
```

it won't work. We are obviously using a wrong syntax, but we can't understand where the error is. 
Thank you in advance to anyone who can answer our question.

This is the full code of the function:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DeckGL, {PathLayer} from 'deck.gl';
import DeckGL, {ScatterplotLayer} from 'deck.gl';
import $ from 'jquery'; 

var tableJSONStringed = null;
var posJSON = [];

//Position tracker

window.setInterval(function(){
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "https://nedo93.000webhostapp.com/phpgetcoords.php",                 
        method: "POST",               
        dataType: "json"    
    });
    request.done(function( msg ) {              
        tableJSONStringed = JSON.stringify(msg, null, " ");
        var count = Object.keys(msg).length;            

        //CYCLE
        for(i=0; i < Object.keys(msg).length; i++) {
         posJSON.push({
        "position": [msg[i].Longitude, msg[i].Latitude],
        "radius": 0.05,
        "color": [255, 255, 0, 255]
    });



        /*posJSON =  [  
            {
                "position": [msg[0].Longitude, msg[0].Latitude],
                "radius": 0.05,
                "color": [255, 255, 0, 255]
            },
            {
                "position": [msg[1].Longitude, msg[1].Latitude],
                "radius": 0.05,
                "color": [255, 0, 0, 255]
            }
        ];*/

    });              
    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        //alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
}, 5000);

export default class DeckGLOverlay extends Component {  

  static get defaultViewport() {
return {
  longitude: 11.25,
  latitude: 43.77,
  zoom: 16,
  maxZoom: 18,
  pitch: 40, //viewport tilt
  bearing: 0
};
  }

  _initialize(gl) {
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
}

 //Add in const { }, new layers's ID
  render() {
const {viewport, scatters, pos, icon, paths, trailLength, time} = this.props;   

//Add another instance of a new layer here:

const layers = [      
  new ScatterplotLayer({
    id: 'scatters',
    data: scatters,     
    radiusScale: 100,
    outline: false
   }),
  new ScatterplotLayer({
    id: 'pos',
    data: posJSON,      
    radiusScale: 100,
    outline: false
   }),    
   new PathLayer({
    id: 'paths',
    data: paths,        
    rounded: true,
    getColor: paths => [255, 0, 0, 255],
    getWidth: paths => 0.03,
    widthScale: 100
  })
];  

return (
  <DeckGL {...viewport} layers={layers} onWebGLInitialized={this._initialize} />
);      
  }    
}
```

and here it is the console output running the for cycle: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kfNT.jpg)

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it won't work". What does it do? Does the javascript console give an errors?

Comment: What is msg? Its important to the question

Comment: can you show us msg?

Comment: Can you show the output of running that loop? I think you can answer your own question just by comparing the two results.

Comment: No the variable is used by deck.gl to draw elements on a map, if we simply declare the object posJson, without for cycle, the elements are correctly displayed, if we try to create it dinamically, the elements just will not appear, no errors given.

Comment: This is probably because the deck.gl library is attempting to draw the elements before the posJson is populated by the loop. Make sure it is populated before you attempt to draw any elements.

Comment: msg is not important, is just an array with some coordinates, given by an ajax request.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without this no one can help

Comment: Lansana, but if we simply create the object without the for cycle, in the same position, it will work.

Comment: @EdoardoBianchi Can you show an example of your code? Just show the loop part and then the part where you attempt to use the results of the loop to draw elements. I can't imagine how it would not work in the way you describe, if it is a synchronous process and the draw elements function is not called until the loop is finished and generated the data which is an exact mirror of the hardcoded version that works. So there is a gotcha in there somewhere that you're not taking into consideration, probably some asynchronous code.

Comment: I edited the question with the full function called to create that object

Comment: Where are you using the `posJSON` variable at? As I stated, this looks like it's a problem with asynchronous code. You populate the data *after* the response comes back from your HTTP request, which means based on how long that response took, 99% of the time your draw elements function already ran before the `posJSON` was populated if you are not drawing the elements in that same response callback.

Comment: I edited adding the whole code of the file

Comment: @EdoardoBianchi All you have to do is simply move the "draw elements" function (whatever it's called) into the `request.done` callback. It's that simple. You can't call it until you've populated the `posJSON` with the results from the response... Otherwise nothing will happen since you initialize it as an empty array and call it before it is populated.

Comment: This could be possibly CORS error. when I tried, I got the error, XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://nedo93.000webhostapp.com/phpgetcoords.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @JacobNelson It's a CORS error for you, because you probably don't have access to that server. I'm sure it works for OP.

Comment: We have the CORS extension on Firefox, the ajax request is working just fine, the problem is only the for cycle, only that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var posJSON = [];
var msg = [
    {Longitude: 1, Latitude:11, radius: 0.01, color: [221,2,32,1]},
    {Longitude: 2, Latitude:21, radius: 0.11, color: [321,2,23,1]},
    {Longitude: 3, Latitude:31, radius: 0.41, color: [521,2,22,1]},
    {Longitude: 4, Latitude:41, radius: 0.11, color: [121,2,02,1]},
    {Longitude: 5, Latitude:51, radius: 0.32, color: [253,2,22,1]},
]
msg.forEach(function(obj) {
    posJSON.push({
        "position": [obj.Longitude, obj.Latitude],
        "radius": obj.radius,
        "color": obj.color
    });
});

console.log(posJSON);
```

Comment: This does not work in the context of his questions example code. This is synchronous code, his code is asynchronous because of the AJAX call. Read the comments; he can populate the data just fine, so your looping logic is redundant. It is the fact that his drawing function is called before his data is populated which is giving the error.

Comment: It doesn't matter, as he is getting the "msg" object once the async call is done.

Comment: It does matter... if you call `myFunc` which uses the `msg` object when `msg` is not yet populated, then when the response comes back you can populate `msg` all you want but nothing will happen because you already called the function. Either you have to call the function a second time then, or defer calling it until the response comes back and after you populate `msg` with the response results. This is how asynchronous programming works.

Comment: What is the obj object in this example?

Comment: @Lansana: I thought request.done() will be called once async is done. However he said he is getting proper value assigned to "msg" obj. In that case above example holds good.

Comment: @EdoardoBianchi: 
Obj in the above example refers to the object of an array depending on the iteration.
Please checkout array.forEach function for more details.

Comment: @AnoopGoudar Yes, I'm aware he is getting the correct data. But just try to understand this: the first thing that happens in his code is he sets `posJSON` to an empty array. The next thing that happens is his view is rendered and the draw elements function is called using `posJSON`, which is an empty array. THIS is the problem. The data is not populated until many milliseconds later when the HTTP response comes back. But by then it's too late because the draw elements function has already been called. So as I stated, he must either call it a second time after the response, or defer calling it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying Lansana, but I don't understand why everything works fine if I just declare posJSON without using the for cycle.

Comment: Where are you declaring posJSON when it works? Are you declaring it in that same `request.done` function, or somewhere outside of it?

Comment: It is declared in the same request.done function, yes.

Comment: Can you log `obj` in each iteration of that `forEach`? Is it the data you are looking for? Regardless of whether it works then, I still believe you need to call the draw elements function after you loop through, because if it is called outside of the `request.done` function then as I stated this is a race condition created by the asynchronous code.

Comment: No sorry, I edited the wrong code for a couple minutes, I adjusted it, we are trying to use the for cycle, not forEach

Comment: Oh alright no worries. But can you try to log each item in the iteration of the for loop? Let me know if the data is what you are expecting on each iteration. Then log the final output of `posJSON` after the loop has run, and compare it with the hardcoded value that works. If they are twins, then we can proceed from there. If they are not twins, your loop logic is wrong.